# Robots.txt file for multi site sitecore implementation

Tags: seo

Is there an example available for the `robots.txt` file on how it should look for a multisite implementation of Sitecore?

Since there is a single `robots.txt` file available on the file system - is there a way of having the required information on a physical file as opposed to generating it on the fly based on the website domain it was requested through?

Comment: Please specify your question more in detail. This is too broad to answer without lot of assumptions

Comment: In this instance, I think you'll have better luck using https://moz.com/learn/seo/robots-meta-directives meta directives. Can setup a metahead rendering that has a data source that takes the values required to output what you need the directives to do.

Comment: Durga, please do follow Peter's instruction and add more information. This does have potential to be a good question!

Answer (score 6):

Sitecore SXA has a good implementation of this. They register it as a [HttpRequestBegin pipeline handler](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/18/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/the-sxa-pipelines.html#UUID-e8167863-1d42-9f12-7a74-ae425e466ffc_id__getControlEditability).

Very simplified version of how it works (as I understand it)

- Check the request url ends with /robots.txt
- Get the context site and make sure we want to process the request for the given site
- Check the cache for data for the context site, write it to the response if it exists
- Get the content from the context site: /sitecore/content/*Tenant*/*Site*/Settings item "Robots content" field
- If it's empty prefill it with a default value (such as deny all)
- Check if a sitemap is available and append it to the content
- Add the content to the cache, and write it to the response

This is a great way as it is high performance and also allows the robots.txt content to be easily editable.

Answer (score 3):

While it is possible to implement a solution with physical files, this approach has some disadvantages:

- To apply a change you have to physically change a file on the server.
- If you have scaled setup with multiple CD server, you would have to apply changes to robots.txt on **each** of the servers.

In contrary, if you generate robots.txt files on the fly based on a hostname and store robots.txt content in Sitecore items, you would have a central place to manage, which would work across all your CD servers.

If you still wanna go for a file-based solution, you could consider using IIS URL rewrite module:

- Have a robots.txt file per website, e.g site1.robots.txt, site2.robots.txt
- Setup IIS rewrite rules to process the /robots.txt requests and rewrite file path based on the hostname.

From top of my head, this could look something like this:

```
<rule name="Multisite robots.txt">
  <match url="^robots\.txt$" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="{HTTP_HOST}.robots.txt" />
</rule>
```

And if you decide to go for dynamic robots.txt generation, there are tons of examples you can find in the internet, e.g https://sitecoreclimber.wordpress.com/2014/07/27/sitecore-multisite-robots-txt/ or even Marketplace modules https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/U/Ultimate_Sitemap_XML.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The below steps you can use for both Robots and Sitemap. If you want to implement only for Robots then you can skip the Sitemap template field and conditions in class.

1. Create a new Template with two fields Sitemap and Robots.
2. Inherit the above template on the Home page template of both Site nodes.
3. Create a patch file:
   This patch file will have one pre-processor to allow the URL extension for XML and Txt files and another processor in the httpRequestBegin pipeline to serve Sitemap and Robots txt files.

```
<pipelines>
<preprocessRequest>
                <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.PreprocessRequest.FilterUrlExtensions, Sitecore.Kernel">
                    <param desc="Allowed extensions (comma separated)">aspx, ashx, asmx, txt, xml</param>
                </processor>
            </preprocessRequest>
<httpRequestBegin>
                <processor type="WebsiteNameSpace.ProjectName.RobotsSitemapTextProcessor, WebsiteNameSpace.ProjectName"
                           patch:before="processor[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.UserResolver, Sitecore.Kernel']" resolve="true" />
            </httpRequestBegin>
</pipelines>
```

4. Create a class in your project for the custom processor and use the below code.

```
public class RobotsSitemapTextProcessor : HttpRequestProcessor
    {
        public override void Process(HttpRequestArgs args)
        {
            try
            {
                HttpContext currentContext = HttpContext.Current;
                if (currentContext == null) return;

                string requestedURL = currentContext.Request.Url.ToString().ToLower().Trim();
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(requestedURL) || (!requestedURL.EndsWith("robots.txt") && !requestedURL.EndsWith("sitemap.xml"))) return;

                var isRobotsRequest = requestedURL.EndsWith("robots.txt");
                var defaultContent = isRobotsRequest ? $"User-agent: * {Environment.NewLine} Disallow: /sitecore" : $"<sitemap> {Environment.NewLine} </sitemap>";

                if (Sitecore.Context.Site != null && Sitecore.Context.Database != null)
                {
                    Item homeNode = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(Sitecore.Context.Site.StartPath);
                    if (homeNode != null)
                    {
                        var contentField = isRobotsRequest ? homeNode.Fields["RobotsContent"] : homeNode.Fields["SitemapContent"];

                        if (contentField != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(contentField.Value))
                            defaultContent = contentField.Value;
                    }
                }

                currentContext.Response.ContentType = isRobotsRequest ? "text/plain" : "text/xml";
                currentContext.Response.Write(defaultContent);
                currentContext.Response.End();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error("SitemapRobots", ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

5. Browse the sitemap and robots pages.

See the blog post for more details: [Sitemap and Robots in Sitecore Multisite](https://himmatsinghdulawat.blogspot.com/2023/06/sitemap-and-robots-in-sitecore-multisite.html)